# AttributeError: module 'pyvista' has no attribute 'PolyData'

Tags: python, pyvista

I am trying to use `pyvista.PolyData` in the following code, however I keep getting this error:

```
 "AttributeError: module 'pyvista' has no attribute 'PolyData'"
```

Can you please help me in resolving this issue? The python version being used is 3.6. Thank you

```
import pyvista as pv
points_3d_boundary_upper = points_3d_boundary_ordered.copy()
points_3d_boundary_upper[:, 0] -= factor * normal_vector[0]
points_3d_boundary_upper[:, 1] -= factor * normal_vector[1]
points_3d_boundary_upper[:, 2] -= factor * normal_vector[2]

# Initiate mesh with lower and upper boundary points
mesh_points_components = [points_3d_boundary_lower, points_3d_boundary_upper]
extruded_boundary = pv.PolyData(np.concatenate(mesh_points_components))
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue, the import is working on my side.
Have you tried importing directly the module: `from pyvista import PolyData`?

Comment: I tried, now it shows: ImportError: cannot import name 'PolyData'

Comment: By the way, I am using Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Comment: What about reinstalling pyvista?

Comment: You probably have a file called `pyvista.py` in the same directory which shadows the package named `pyvista`.

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate, assuming it has the same issue I just mentioned. If your problem is not this, then please [edit] your question with a full traceback so that we have a [mcve], and I'll reopen it.